# Как создать массив shared_ptr на с++ в Xcode?

Tags: c++

Влетает ошибка No matching constructor for initialization of 'shared_ptr' на строке инциализации масива в Xcode. В чем ошибка не понимаю.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    shared_ptr<int[]> p(new int[5]);

    p[3] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Во-первых тут у вас не массив shared_ptr , а один shared_ptr c массивом int. Во-вторых код рабочий, а если он у вас не собирается, то следует указывать версию и параметры компилятора, а лучше сразу ссылку на godbolt.

Comment: По моему до С++17 не было  возможности для  shared_ptr массива. Для компилятора версии до С++17 это ошибка.

Comment: Ide тут то при чем? данные по тулчейну в студию